# Content of textarea not showing up on render

Tags: html, textarea

Can't seem to get the inner content of textarea tags to show up on load. Sample HTML I'm experiencing problem with:

`<textarea name="textareaname" rows="8" cols="80">Text area content to edit on load.</textarea>`

Inspect element shows the HTML renders exactly like that, complete with the innerHTML. It's just not showing the text in the textarea. Any idea what could be causing this?

Render in inspect element:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: can u provide the rest of the html and css I think something overriding your textarea

Comment: @user3808887 it's a WordPress theme, but I just dropped the textarea sample into the content and gave a screenshot of the render. Problem exists in Safari and Chrome.

Comment: probably the css is the issue. Add the class attribute for the textarea

Comment: what are you using as client side script?

Comment: Hey, have you been able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with you when trying set Textarea content by ajax

```
$("textarea).html(content) <- this way is not correct
$("textarea).val(content) <- it work
```

Hope this helps!